# How to obtain the result of n(n-1)(n-2) / 6

Tags: python, algorithm

In my Python book, the question asks to prove the value of `x` after running the following code:

```
x = 0
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(i+1, n):
        for k in range(j+1, n):
            x += 1
```

What I could see is that:

```
i = 0;  j=1;  k=2:  from 2 to n, x+=1, (n-2) times 1
i = 1;  j=2;  k=3:  from 3 to n, x+=1, (n-3) times 1
...
i=n-3;  j=n-2; k=n-1: from n-1 to n, x+=1, just 1
i=n-2;  j=n-1; k=n doesn't add 1
```

So it seems that the `x` is the sum of series of (n-2) + (n-3) + ... + 1?
I am not sure how to get to the answer of `n(n-1)(n-2)/6`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to view this is that you have `n` values and three nested loops which are constructed to have non-overlapping ranges.  Thus the number of iterations possible is equal to the number of ways to choose three unique values from `n` items, or [`n choose 3`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) = `n!/(3!(n-3)!)` = `n(n-1)(n-2)/3*2*1` = `n(n-1)(n-2)/6`.

Comment: Thank you pjs, this is a definitely a smart way to view it!

Answer (score 1):

Just write the `for` loops as a sigma: `S = sum_{i=1}^n sum_{j=i+1}^n sum_{k = j + 1}^n (1)`.

Try to expand the sum from inner to outer:
`S = sum_{i=1}^n sum_{j=i+1}^n (n - j) = sum_{i=1}^n n(n-i) - ((i+1) + (i+2) + ... + n) = sum_{i=1}^n n(n-i) - ( 1+2+...+n - (1+2+...+i)) = sum_{i=1}^n n(n-i) -(n(n+1)/2 - i(i+1)/2) = sum_{i=1}^n  n(n+1)/2 + i(i+1)/2 - n*i = n^2(n+1)/2 + sum_{i=1}^n (i^2/2 + i/2 - n*i)`.
If open this sum and simplify it (it is straightforward) you will get `S = n(n-1)(n-2)/6`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a **mathematical model** of the algorithm, known as binomial coefficient (combinations). In analysis of algorithms you can use this form : **N^k/k!**
In your code you have a case **without repetition** that's why n*(n **-1** )*(n **-2** ) / 3!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).